# What is this called: Two linearly dependent vectors where one is a nonnegative multiple of the other?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, terminology, definition

Two vectors $x$ and $y$ drawn from a real vector space are **linearly dependent** if
$$ \text{there exists $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x=\alpha y$ or $y=\alpha x$.}$$

My question is very simple: What do we say if we are in the case when we know even more, namely:
$$ \text{there exists $\alpha\geq 0$ such that $x=\alpha y$ or $y=\alpha x$}~?$$

Haven't found anything here on stackexchange or on the web, but somebody must have given this case a name. A reference would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "The vectors $x$ and $y$ point in the same direction" is an almost convincing way of saying this. Of course, we have to interpret the sentence in the broad sense (allowing for zero vectors, and for the 'direction' of the zero vector to be the same as any other vector).

Comment: "Nonnegative linear dependence" would make sense here. A vector can also be a "nonnegative linear combination" of other vectors.

Comment: The tag [terminology] might help for your question.

Comment: @soupless thank you, added!

Comment: Related: [Do parallel vectors have identical unit vector?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3312314/do-parallel-vectors-have-identical-unit-vector). [tl;dr] If you say that $\,x,y\,$ are ["*antiparallel vectors*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiparallel_(mathematics)#Antiparallel_vectors), it will most likely be understood as $\,\alpha \lt 0\,$. However, "*parallel vectors*" might be understood as either $\,\alpha \in \mathbb R\,$ or $\,\alpha \ge 0\,$ depending on context and previous definitions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_combination

Comment: Some people call them “co-directed vectors”.

Comment: I might call them _conically dependent_. There's a related notion of _convex dependence_.

Comment: @mr_e_man I like this the best - any references for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460902/what-is-this-called-two-linearly-dependent-vectors-where-one-is-a-nonnegative-m/4463478#comment9345898_4460902), they are usually called vectors "in the same direction".

Since you have the `reference-request` tag, see for instance,

- Chapter 13.1 of
  [*Calculus: Single and Multivariable (8th Edition)*](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Calculus%3A+Single+and+Multivariable,+8th+Edition-p-9781119696551) by Deborah Hughes-Hallett, Andrew M. Gleason, William G. McCallum :

> [image]

- Chapter 1.2.1 of *Vectors in Physics and Engineering* by Alan Durrant:

> [image]

---

[Added]
If you include the zero scalar as well, people simply call it a "nonnegative scalar multiple". See for instance,

*Nonlinear Conjugate Gradient Methods for Unconstrained Optimization*
By Neculai Andrei:

> [image]

*Completely Positive Matrices*
By Abraham Berman, Naomi Shaked-monderer:

> [image]

---

Remark.

In a real vector space $V$, the notion of "nonnegative multiple" is not very useful because is not closed under the vector operators. It is more useful when one has an [ordered vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_vector_space), on which one can consider a [positive linear functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_linear_functional), where, in the definition, one uses positive scalars.

---

As [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460902/what-is-this-called-two-linearly-dependent-vectors-where-one-is-a-nonnegative-m/4463478#comment9352489_4460902) mentioned, When you consider only nonnegative linear combinations, there is a notion called "[conical combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_combination)":

> Given a finite number of vectors $x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n}$ in a real vector space, a conical combination, conical sum, or weighted sum of these vectors is a vector of the form
> $$
> \alpha_{1} x_{1}+\alpha_{2} x_{2}+\cdots+\alpha_{n} x_{n}
> $$
> where $\alpha_{i}$ are non-negative real numbers.
> The name derives from the fact that a conical sum of vectors defines a cone (possibly in a lower-dimensional subspace).

See the linked article and references therein.

Comment: Thanks - I need to include the case when the scalar is $0$ though.

Comment: @max_zorn: see the added references.

Comment: I have awarded you the points to not waste them but this is clearly not what I was looking for. In fact, some of it restates my subject line. But thanks for the effort.

Comment: @max_zorn: Thanks for the bounty. But I honestly do not understand your comment. You look for references and I give you the references in different cases. What else are you looking for? With all due respect, based on what research do you think "somebody must have given this case a name"?

Comment: If you want "convex dependence", then try [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Convex_Polytopes/ET04AAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=convex+dependence&pg=PA1&printsec=frontcover).

Answer (score 2):

I think they are called parallel or collinear vectors.

 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Opposite,_parallel,_and_antiparallel_vectors

Answer (score 2):

If one vector is a nonzero scalar multiple of the other, we can say that they are either *parallel* (in the case that the scalar is positive) or *antiparallel* (in the case that the scalar is negative).

The above assumes that our vector space is defined over an ordered field, like $\mathbb R$, in which it makes sense to classify scalars as "positive" or "negative".  If we are instead working over an unordered field, like $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb Z/(p)$ for a prime $p$, then the words "positive" and "negative" are not meaningful, and the distinction between "parallel" and "antiparallel" is similarly not meaningful.  In this case, we would probably just say that "each is a scalar multiple of the other".  If you really want a single word or phrase for the general case, I would probably call the vectors "parallel", which I think most people would understand as having the intended meaning.